# RegEx to search a string to have not more than 2 letters

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I write a JavaScript RegEx with the below requirements.

- Alphanumeric only
- String length should be between 9-10
- Can have a maximum of 2 letters and a minimum of 0 in any order in the string

Below is what I have written. Seems to work partially.

```
\b(?=.*[a-zA-Z]{0,2})([a-zA-Z0-9]{9,10})\b
```

This seems to work but accepts more than 3 letters too.

- 1234567890 (Match)
- 12345B7T90 (Match)
- AA123D4324 (Match but it should not be a match because it has more that 2 letters)

Comment: Character or letter?

Comment: Letters. Corrected it :)

Comment: The last 2 requirements: length should be 9-10 and can have a maximum of 2 letters makes it quite a challenge. Can you clarify the use case for this?

Comment: It's to validate the Australian driver license number. I have simplified the requirements in my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\b(?!(\d*[a-zA-Z]){3,})\w{9,10}\b
```

It starts by a Word boundary `'\b'`, then it uses a negative look ahead for:

`\d*` zero or more digits, followed by:

`[a-zA-Z]` a letter. This should not be:

`{3,}` 3 or more of that.

If success, match between 9 and 10 of a `Word` character, and finally a Word `boundary`.